# Teamviewer and "multichannel routing"?

Tags: teamviewer

What the hell does this even mean?

> Multichannel routing for outstanding high performance

[I've never seen such awesome marketing text.](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/licensing/index.aspx)

I'm trying to make an educated decision between two products, neither of which I can probably afford.

Comment: Why not ask them...?

Comment: Your best bet is to call them, any time Monday to Thursday from 6:00 AM to 12:00 AM (ET) or Friday from 6:00 AM to 6:00 PM (ET) at 1 800 951 4573 or email them at sales@teamviewer.com .

Answer (score 2):

So I asked the question...

> Dear Evan,
>
> Thank you for your message.
>
> Multi-channel routing is an additional feature available in the
>   Premium- and the Corporate license. **Should TeamViewer notice a traffic
>   bottleneck in the transmission of the data, TeamViewer will route your
>   traffic securely through the fastest calculated connection through our
>   servers.** I do hope this information is helpful for you.

I guess normally if if there is a bottleneck they route your stuff through the slowest servers? Lol. Not a single idea what they're talking about...

Comment: Sounds like they will relay your connection through their server. Given ISP interconnects the shortest path may not be the fastest path.